# jQuery - prevent same click function to run more than once at a time

Tags: jquery

I just started to lern JavaScript and jQuery today, and got my first problem wich causes me real headache. I've been searching for hours to solve this, but none of the solutions did work.

My problem is: I made a "carousel" website, where content is slided left or right, if clicked on a menu link.

Everything works fine, but if u click on another menulink again before the animation of the click function has finished, the content slides away and is not at the right position.

I've tryed promise().done(), flags, callback and so on, but nothing worked for me :( maybe I did it just wrong..

I'm searching for a solution, to block this click function until it finishes, or better making a queue of this function,  to run after another, but not at the same time.

Here is my JS code, I know it's not perfect and could be solved better, but like I said, i just started to learn this stuff today and I'm not yet familiar with the syntax and so on.

```
    var gotoPage = function(pos) {

    if(pos == 'home') {
        $('li#home').css({"opacity" : 1});
        $('li#home').css({"left" : "1700px"});
        $('li#home').animate({"left" : "0px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');

        $('li#news').animate({"left" : "-1700px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');
        $('li#news').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 0);
        $('li#galery').animate({"left" : "-1700px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');
        $('li#galery').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 0);
    } else if (pos == 'news') {
        $('li#news').css({"opacity" : 1});
        $('li#news').css({"left" : "1700px"});
        $('li#news').animate({"left" : "0px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');

        $('li#home').animate({"left" : "-1700px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');
        $('li#home').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 0);
        $('li#galery').animate({"left" : "-1700px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');
        $('li#galery').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 0);
    } else if (pos == 'galery') {
        $('li#galery').css({"opacity" : 1});
        $('li#galery').css({"left" : "1700px"});
        $('li#galery').animate({"left" : "0px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');

        $('li#news').animate({"left" : "-1700px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');
        $('li#news').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 0);
        $('li#home').animate({"left" : "-1700px"}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');
        $('li#home').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 0);
    }

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    hideAll();
    autoSelect();

    $('#home').click(function(){        
        gotoPage(posHome);
    });

    $('#news').click(function(){
        gotoPage(posNews);
    });

    $('#galery').click(function(){      
        gotoPage(posGalery);
    });

});
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Not an answer, but the first thing you should know about jQuery is chaining. The `$(...)` function is slow; use `$('li#home').css({"opacity" : 1}).css({"left" : "1700px"});`. Or better yet, `$('li#home').css({"opacity" : 1, "left" : "1700px"});`. The latter is especially true of `animate` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but you're looking for this -

```
$('#home').click(function(){  
    if( $(this).is(':animated') ) return;
    gotoPage(posHome);
});

$('#news').click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':animated') ) return;
    gotoPage(posNews);
});

$('#galery').click(function(){     
    if( $(this).is(':animated') ) return;
    gotoPage(posGalery);
});
```

See here about testing jQuery selections for [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

BradGreens answer looks the most correct.

Here is an alternative for fun:

You can have a "currentlyAnimating" boolean to tell if animation is still performing. 
Then on animation complete, set it to false;

```
var animating = false

if(pos == 'home' && !animating) {
    animating = true;
    $('li#galery').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 100,  function() {
        // Animation complete.
        animating = false;
    }););
}
```

Comment: same solution as my first, didn't work for me, cause I didn't put the function into the animate, but at the end of the if statement ^^ this one works. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something slightly different - namely allowing a click on any of the three elements to "hijack" the progress of a previous incomplete click-action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $currentePage = null;

    var gotoPage = function(pos) {
        if($currentePage) {
            $currentePage.stop().animate({'left' : '-1700px'}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint').css('opacity', 0);
        }
        $currentePage = $('li#' + pos).css({
            'opacity' : 1,
            'left' : '1700px'
        }).animate({'left' : '0px'}, speed, 'easeInOutQuint');
    }

    hideAll();
    autoSelect();

    $('#home, #news, #galery').click(function() {
        gotoPage(this.id);
    });
    $('#home').trigger('click');
});
```

As you can see, `gotoPage()` is much reduced and works as follows :

- kills any animation that is currently running
- returns the current element to its rest state
- animates the requested element to its active state.

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, but I learned very much from this, thank you so much :)